# Escape special characters in email string sent via http body

Tags: ios, http

I have an iOS app that sends an email address to a server via the http body as below:

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"grant_type=password&username=%@&password=%@",emailAddress,password];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://dev.flippie.com/OAuth/token"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

This works fine unless the email address contains special characters ('+' for example) which then brakes the http request.
How can i escape any characters that might cause and issue within the email string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the string with `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"grant_type=password&username=%@&password=%@", [emailAddress stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], password];
```

Comment: But its not the URL that is the issue its the http body?

Answer (score 0):

The previously selected answer using stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding has been deprecated in iOS 9.0. The new method is stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters

```
NSString *escapedEmail = [email stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet]];
```

There are a few different Characters sets built in as well as you can create your own.

```
@interface NSCharacterSet (NSURLUtilities)
+ (NSCharacterSet *)URLUserAllowedCharacterSet;
+ (NSCharacterSet *)URLPasswordAllowedCharacterSet;
+ (NSCharacterSet *)URLHostAllowedCharacterSet;
+ (NSCharacterSet *)URLPathAllowedCharacterSet;
+ (NSCharacterSet *)URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet;
+ (NSCharacterSet *)URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet;
```